# MS SQL for XML query

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-loop

Need Some Help.

Currently have 2 tables.

```
#head

PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
------ ------ ------
AAA    BBB    CCC
```

and

```
#body

NAME                 SEX                  EMAIL
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Tania                Female               mail@femail.com
Sergey               male                 mail@mail.com
```

By using next query I am getting next result:

QUERY:

```
SELECT
        PARAM1,
        PARAM2,
        PARAM3,
        (SELECT
            NAME,
            SEX,
            EMAIL
        FROM #body
        FOR XML RAW('body'),ELEMENTS,TYPE
        ) AS bodyS
    FROM #head as HEAD
    FOR XML AUTO
```

Current Result:

```
<HEAD PARAM1="AAA" PARAM2="BBB" PARAM3="CCC">
  <bodyS>
    <body>
      <NAME>Tania</NAME>
      <SEX>Female</SEX>
      <EMAIL>mail@femail.com</EMAIL>
    </body>
    <body>
      <NAME>Sergey</NAME>
      <SEX>male</SEX>
      <EMAIL>mail@mail.com</EMAIL>
    </body>
  </bodyS>
</HEAD>
```

Expected result:

```
<HEAD PARAM1="AAA" PARAM2="BBB" PARAM3="CCC">
    <body>
      <NAME>Tania</NAME>
      <SEX>Female</SEX>
      <EMAIL>mail@femail.com</EMAIL>
    </body>
    <body>
      <NAME>Sergey</NAME>
      <SEX>male</SEX>
      <EMAIL>mail@mail.com</EMAIL>
    </body>
</HEAD>
```

Could somebody help Me to figure-out how can I reach expected result.

## Thanks to everyone in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@` in the column name will create a attribute instead of element.
Use sub query with `FOR XML PATH` for creating "internal" elements from returned rows.

```
SELECT 
    'AAA' AS '@Param1'
    , 'BBB' AS '@Param2'
    , 'CCC' AS '@Param3'
    , (SELECT Name, Sex, Email FROM [yourTable] FOR XML PATH ('BODY'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('HEAD')
```

Comment: Ruery Result:
<HEAD Param1="AAA" Param2="BBB" Param3="CCC">&lt;BODY&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Tania&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Sex&gt;Female&lt;/Sex&gt;&lt;Email&gt;mail@femail.com&lt;/Email&gt;&lt;/BODY&gt;&lt;BODY&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Sergey&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Sex&gt;male&lt;/Sex&gt;&lt;Email&gt;mail@mail.com&lt;/Email&gt;&lt;/BODY&gt;</HEAD>

not really what I am looking for.
But anyway, thanks.

Comment: @FirmackBendera, sorry the `TYPE` parameter was missed. Check updated query

Comment: Thanks A lot  ! 
Works as expected ! =)